# Why an api request is going to web.php route from api.php route?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, validation, routes

I am working with laravel RestfulApi project. I am facing an unexpected trouble. When I try to send an API request to api.php route, it goes to the web.php route. But if I don't use validation in my controller file, the code runs well. I only get the above problem when using validation. Below is my code.

---

**Api.php Routes**

---

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/showingData','UserContactController@show');
Route::post('/storingData','UserContactController@store');
```

---

**Web.php Routes**

```
 <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


    Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
    });
```

---

**UserContactController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UserContact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required|max:5'
        ]);
        $userContact=new UserContact();
        $userContact->name=$request->input('name');
        $userContact->email=$request->input('email');
        $userContact->description=$request->input('description');
        $userContact->visibility=$request->input('visibility');
        $userContact->created_by=$request->input('created_by');
        $userContact->save();
        return response()->json([
            "message"=>"student record created"
        ],201);
    }
}
```

---

**UserContac.php Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserContact extends Model
{
    //
}


----------
```

**My Postman url**

```
 http://amaderproject.test/api/storingData
```

Comment: Set the `Accept` header in postman to `application/json` otherwise validation failiures cause a redirect instead of sending a JSON error response

Comment: what is you laravel version? did you edit RouteServiceProvider ? if Not, paste here  MapApiRoute and MapWebRoute from Routeserviceprovider in your project